# Variable is undefined when component is re-rendered in React

Tags: reactjs

In my app, I have a list of university departments. When you click a specific department, you are taken to the department landing page (`/department/:deptId`). I am using React Router's `useParams` hook to get the department id from the URL and then find that specific department object from my array of departments passed down as props.

This works fine when navigating from the list of departments to the individual department page, but if I refresh the page, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "Name", dept is undefined`

My code is below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Department = props => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [dept, setDept] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const unit = props.depts.find(item => item.Id === Number(id));
    setDept(unit);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{dept.Name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Department;
```

I'm not sure why this happens. My understanding is that the props should remain the same, and the `useEffect` should run when the page is refreshed. Any idea what I'm missing?

More code below:

The `depts` array is passed as props from the `App` component, which is getting it from an axios call in a Context API component.

```
import { UnitsContext } from './contexts/UnitsContext';

function App() {
  const { units } = useContext(UnitsContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/people" component={Persons} />
        <Route exact path="/department/:id">
          <Department depts={units} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

// Context Component. Provider wraps `index.js`

export const UnitsContext = createContext();

export const UnitsContextProvider = props => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:5000';

  const [units, setUnits] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${url}/api/units`)
      .then(res => {
        setUnits(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <UnitsContext.Provider value={{ units }}>
      {props.children}
    </UnitsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where are `depts` coming from? When you refresh the page, whole App gets reinitialized.

Comment: With this part of code it totally should work as `dept` initial state is `{}`

Comment: You may want to consider putting an `if` statement before your `setDept` call so you aren't setting the value to `undefined` if you pass in an id which doesn't exist

Comment: `depts` is being passed from the `App` component, which is where my `Department` route is declared. `App` is getting `depts` from an API call in Context Api.

When I put an `if` statement, it doesn't crash, but I get an empty page on refresh because nothing is being passed.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is most probably with this,

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unit = props.depts.find(item => item.Id === Number(id));
    setDept(unit); // <<
  }, [id]);
```

Nothing else in ur code sets State except `setDept(unit);`
So, My best guess is `props.depth` find matches nothing and returns `null`. Thats why `dept.Name` results with the error

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find),

> The *value* of the *first element* in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, **`undefined` is returned**

Comment: That seems right. When I `console.log(props.depts)` in the `useEffect`, I get the expected array when coming from the lists, but it logs as undefined when I refresh. I'm not sure why this is the case. I'm getting `depts` from an axios call that I'm doing in a context api component. It's then brought into the App component through a `useContext` hook. I've edited my original post to include this code

Comment: @Rasha whats the initial state of `useContext` ?